# how to return a list/tuple of multiple dictionaries as an output from a function in Flask app?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, flask

I have a requirement from a function to return something like this when a data is sent by `Postman`:

`[{"spam" : False, "accuracy" : "0.2"}, {"multi" : True, "accuracy" : "0.5"},{"single" : False, "accuracy" : "0.3"}]`

I have the following function as:

```
app = Flask(__name__,template_folder='templates') # instantiate flask api
 
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def format_result(my,pred):
    result = ({'multi':False, 'accuracy':float(my[0])}, {'single':False, 'accuracy':float(my[1])}, {'spam':False, 'accuracy':float(my[2])})

    if pred == 'multi':
        result[0]['multi'] == True
    elif pred == 'single':
        result[1]['single'] == True
    else:
        result[2]['spam'] == True
    
    return result
```

`my` is a `numpy array` say `my=np.array([0.13433,0.33353,0.24254])` so I was having problems serialisation so I thought of converting it to `float()`

I am still having problems as the error is:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flask.jsonify

See https://kite.com/python/docs/flask.jsonify for example

And https://medium.com/octopus-wealth/returning-json-from-flask-cf4ce6fe9aeb

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, albeit you surely meant `=` instead of `==` and wanted to output a list rather than a tuple. This said, the error results from somewhere else:

```
import numpy as np

my = np.array([0.13433, 0.33353, 0.24254])

result = [{'multi': False, 'accuracy': float(my[0])}, {'single': False, 'accuracy': float(my[1])},
          {'spam': False, 'accuracy': float(my[2])}]

pred = "single"
if pred == 'multi':
    result[0]['multi'] = True
elif pred == 'single':
    result[1]['single'] = True
else:
    result[2]['spam'] = True

print(result)
```

This yields

```
[{'multi': False, 'accuracy': 0.13433}, {'single': True, 'accuracy': 0.33353}, {'spam': False, 'accuracy': 0.24254}]
```

Comment: @Deshwal: But it does not result from the code you posted. Please post the full error stack.

Comment: I think you are missing the above two lines. It is not about the `python` but the `flask`. When you run the exact code and an api hit using postman, you'll get the same